# How to get the jQuery `$(this)` id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the `id` of the element that triggered the jQuery `.change()` function?
The function itself works properly, but I need a specific action for a selector with `id="next"`.

```
$("select").change(function() {
    [...snip....]
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );  // <---- not working
}
```

Any ideas why the alert above isn't working?

Comment: It looks like it works to me... http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nGtjR/1/

Comment: Are you trying to get the id of the select element your change handler is attached to?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`this` is the DOM element on which the event was hooked. `this.id` is its ID. No need to wrap it in a jQuery instance to get it, the `id` property reflects the attribute reliably on all browsers.

```
$("select").change(function() {    
    alert("Changed: " + this.id);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ufafi3)

You're not doing this in your code sample, but if you were watching a container with several form elements, that would give you the ID of the *container*. If you want the ID of the element that triggered the event, you could get that from the [`event` object's](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) `target` property:

```
$("#container").change(function(event) {
    alert("Field " + event.target.id + " changed");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ufafi3/2)

(jQuery ensures that the `change` event bubbles, even on IE where it doesn't natively.)

Comment: What makes you think `.id` is that reliable?

Comment: @ajax333221: Do you have some reason to think otherwise? I've used it in IE5.5 onward, Chrome and Firefox since they started, the old Netscape Navigator, Opera for more than a decade, Safari, Konqueror, Midori, etc. It's [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901) in DOM2 HTML, and it's in [very early versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/CR-DOM-Level-2-19991210/html.html#ID-63534901) of that doc. I'd say you won't find a browser in general (or probably even limited) use which doesn't reflect `id` on elements -- but I'm interested in the genesis of your comment. :-)

Comment: @T well, the truth is I was looking for references about this for  hours, your post was the best I found, but still I wanted some confirmation with references :-J

Comment: @ajax333221: Gotcha. :-) [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) is the one to look in for this, although [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) -- which is about a *lot* more than HTML -- is increasingly superceding it. Oddly, `id` is missing from the IDL for the [HTML5 definition of `HTMLElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlelement).

Comment: @ajax333221: And the reason it's not there is that it's being defined a level higher up, on an upcoming DOM spec for [`Element`](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-element).

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean that for a select element with an id of "next" you need to perform some specific script?

```
$("#next").change(function(){
    //enter code here
});
```