# Get id + additional string through jQuery to activate CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css

What am I doing wrong here?
I'm trying to get the id of the hovered div through the class, then add the string '-slide' to activate the supposedly sliding transition for each .content.

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
$('.try').hover(function() {
    $(this.id + '-slide').css('right','0px');
});
</script>

<style>
.try {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
 }

.content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -50px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="one" class="try"></div>
<div id="two" class="try"></div>
<div id="three" class="try"></div>
<div id="one-slide" class="content"></div>
<div id="two-slide" class="content"></div>
<div id="three-slide" class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".try").hover(
  function () {
    $('#' + this.id + '-slide').css('right','0px');
  },
  function () {
    $('#' + this.id + '-slide').css('right','-50px');
  }
);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kdx43/)

Comment: Accepted as the answer for the additional fiddle :3

Comment: @LimitBreaker15, Is that so? That's sad A five minutes late answer gets accepted because of the fiddle? ha ha

Answer (score 1):

To select a particular element in jQuery you need `#` for id and `.` for classes just like css.

You probably need this

```
$("#" + this.id + '-slide').css('right','0px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure id just `.id` would work... have you tried this?

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-slide').css('right','0px');
```

Comment: `.id` is equivalent, it's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346238/get-jquery-this-id

Comment: Good point. I'd delete my answer if I could, as it's not helpful.

Comment: Your answer made me think, consider and research  the problem (I also wasn't sure if `.id` is correct), so it was helpful for me ;)

Comment: Yep, all that's missing is the `'#' + ` before `this.id`